# Check the Response status -PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm trying to make **POST REQUEST**

Then checking the  response header status code

200 or 302

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'url' #url
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' } #post data

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

when i try

response.getcode()

the result is 200 even if the result is 302-FOUND
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `urllib2.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

> This function returns a file-like object with three additional
>   methods:
>
> - geturl() — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to determine if a redirect was followed
> - info() — return the meta-information of the page, such as headers, in the form of an mimetools.Message instance (see Quick Reference to
>     HTTP Headers)
> - getcode() — return the HTTP status code of the response.

So you can get the status using

```
status = response.getcode()
```

In the case of redirects, `urlopen` will follow the redirection automatically. Use `response.geturl()` and see if it matches the URL you specified.

Comment: the problem when i check the status from the plugins (the status is 302 Found) if not found ( status is 200-OK) but `getcode()` the result always 200 !

Comment: `urlopen()` can automatically follow redirects, use `response.geturl()` to see if it's different from the URL you specified.

Comment: ok that helped me :)

Comment: another thing please .... when i try response.read() i don't get everything in the source sometimes i just get javascript code only i don't get the html code

Comment: `urllib` should not modify the data, are you sure that the server isn't just returning javascipt in that case? You could try doing `print(response.info())` to dump all the HTTP headers, and inspect `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` (if provided) to see what the server spits out. If it says `Content-Type: application/javascript` for instance, you know that the server only served javascript.

Comment: i need function that is able to read the source code like  in the browser when we click on (view page source)

Comment: `response.read()` should provide just that. There is no rendering or interpretation of the data, just the raw HTTP body, which in web browser is called "page source".

Comment: i tried but when click on page source i get the whole html code from response.read() i don't get that 80% js and 20% html

Comment: Are you sure that the browser sent the exact same POST data as your script? Different POST data can cause the server to send different responses. Even different HTTP request headers such as `User-Agent` can cause it to send completely different data if it so pleases.

Comment: Yes the same POST data :/ but about User-Agent i'm sending the request from python how can it be changed !?

Comment: Supply it in a `dict` when creating the `Request` object, like so: `req = urllib2.Request(url, data, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'})`. You can visit https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending to see all headers that your browser is sending.

Comment: i get the source but some fields ecrypted like that &#x627; any idea ?

Comment: i decrypted it now ^^

Comment: in the post data there is "charset_test" : "%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E2%82%AC%2C%C2%B4%2C%E6%B0%B4%2C%D0%94%2C%D0%84" i think this is the problem i don't know how to send it

Comment: POST data is sometimes URL encoded, sometimes not. So you may need to send it as-is or decode it first with `urllib2.unquote()`.

Comment: when i decode it i get something strange ..can you try?

Comment: And if you know what's this encryption \xd8\xa7\xd9\x84\xd8 please tell me

Comment: Sorry, it's your data. Looks like a comma-separated list of strange symbols. But this is way off from the original question.